# CSS calc() doesn't work as expected on Firefox

Tags: css, css-calc

This code in a CSS block of a div :

```css
--z: calc(1082px - 100%);
--z1: calc(var(--z) * 1000);
--z2: calc(max(var(--z1) * (-1), var(--z1))); /* abs */
--z3: calc((var(--z2) + var(--z1)) / 2);
--z4: calc(min(var(--z3), 1px));
width: calc(var(--z4) * 1082);
```

If --z is negative, then --z4 = 1px.

If --z >= 0, then --z4 = 0px.

This part works well on Chrome and Firefox.
I can observe the result like this :

```css
width: var(--z4);
```

The problem :

```css
width: calc(var(--z4) * 1082);
```

When --z4 = 1px, then width must be equal to 1082px, i.e. 1px * 1082.

Nevertheless, it doesn't work on Firefox. It returns width: 0px.

On Chrome, it work well, width: 1082px.

Please, could someone explain why it doesn't work on Firefox?

---

EDIT :

I wrote the formula in 1 line :

```css
width: calc(min((max(((1082px - 100%) * 1000) * (-1), ((1082px - 100%) * 1000)) + (1082px - 100%) * 1000) / 2, 1px) * 50);
```

I checked the result after adding each piece.
It works well except for the last piece on Firefox (same as for the first version using several variables and functions calc()).

```css
width: calc(min((max(((1082px - 100%) * 1000) * (-1), ((1082px - 100%) * 1000)) + (1082px - 100%) * 1000) / 2, 1px));
```

It returns 0px or 1px. These are the expected values.

But when adding * 50  (or another number) it fails (on Firefox). it returns 0px instead of 50px (1px * 50).

Nevertheless, in case of addition + 50px, it works and returns 51px.

---

EDIT 2

Finally, it seems that Firefox doesn't like when I multiply by 1000.
When I take off  * 1000, then it works well.
Nevertheless, I need to neutralize the decimal part of numbers.
I will be thinking of another solution.

Comment: `calc` is white-space sensitive, play around with that a bit.

Comment: @serraosays do you see any white-space mistake in width: calc(var(--z4) * 1082); ? The code above this line works well in Firefox.

Comment: @Sam, try to remove white spaces around `+` and `*` operations.

Comment: @Azu I tried, but it doesn't fix the problem. Also I checked all lines, and they all work well, except the last one, the one concerning width. I checked the white-space.

Comment: browser don't like too many nested calc() like you have discovered. By the way why not having one formula instead of all these?

Comment: My guess is the way css `var` gets interpreted by the browsers is different and causing the `calc` white space issue to manifest itself. And then you've got nested calc on top of that, just inviting complier problems in the browser.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will give it a try. I will write only one formula.

Comment: @serraosays I will check again the white-space and write only one formula.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is the same after having written the formula in 1 line,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help you. As I can see, the yellow (z2) is far too big, for example it can be 145000px. It seems your formula is wrong.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div')
.forEach(div=>div.insertAdjacentHTML(
 'afterend',
 `<code>${div.getAttribute('style')}</code>
→ <code>${getComputedStyle(div).width}</code> computed.`
));
```

```css
:root {
  --z: calc(1082px - 100%);
  --z1: calc(var(--z) * 1000);
  --z2: calc(max(var(--z1) * (-1), var(--z1)));  /* abs */
  --z3: calc((var(--z2) + var(--z1)) / 2);
  --z4: calc(min(var(--z3), 1px));
}

div {
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

```html
<div style="--bg: red; width: var(--z);"></div>
<div style="--bg: green; width: var(--z1);"></div>
<div style="--bg: yellow; width: var(--z2);"></div>
<div style="--bg: pink; width: var(--z3);"></div>
<div style="--bg: blue; width: var(--z4);"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not the problem. The browsers stand this so big value.

Comment: Again, check your formulas. (z4) is 1px when the browser is narrow, on large browsers it becomes 0.

Comment: 0px or 1px for z4 are the expected values.